# @transactional rollback not working

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, liferay

Below is what I did, I need to implement rollback, using @transactional annotation, but not working as expected, what else need to be done for proper rollback to happen ??   I want that when the code is executed result in db should be "testingOne" , currently it is set to "notRollBacked". Can you please point my mistake.

```
 public Response deleteUser(Request argVO)throws Exception
{
    Users users = UsersLocalServiceUtil.getUsers("sagar");
    users.setUserName("testingOne");
    UsersLocalServiceUtil.updateUsers(users);
    try
    {
        testRollbackFunction();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return new Response();
}


@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.PORTAL, rollbackFor =
    {PortalException.class, SystemException.class})
private void testRollbackFunction() throws Exception
{
    Users users = UsersLocalServiceUtil.getUsers("sagar");
    users.setUserName("notRollbacked");
    UsersLocalServiceUtil.updateUsers(users);
    throw new PortalException();
}
```

***************************Edit 1**************************
I did what was mentioned in answers:

I did taken bean from context

and written a class/bean as

```
  @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.PORTAL, rollbackFor =
{PortalException.class, SystemException.class})
public class RollBack
{

@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.PORTAL, rollbackFor =
    {PortalException.class, SystemException.class})
public void thisWillRollBack() throws Exception
{
    Users users = UsersLocalServiceUtil.getUsers("sagar");
    users.setBarringReason("notRollbacked");
    UsersLocalServiceUtil.updateUsers(users);
    throw new PortalException();
}
```

}

spring xml file bean refrence set as :

```
<bean id="rollBackBean" class="com.alepo.RollBack">

</bean>

public Response myMethod(Request argVO)throws Exception
{
    Users users = UsersLocalServiceUtil.getUsers("sagar");
    users.setBarringReason("testingOne");
    UsersLocalServiceUtil.updateUsers(users);
    try
    {
        Test test = new Test();
        Object obj = test.getBean();
        RollBack rollBack = (RollBack)obj;
        rollBack.thisWillRollBack();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new Response();
}
```

#################EDIT 4

now calling rollback function as :

```
 RollBack rollBack =     (RollBack)PortalBeanLocatorUtil.getBeanLocator().locate("rollBackBean");

        rollBack.thisWillRollBack();
```

No Test class in picture now ...no new anywhere ...

still NOT WORKING .......

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 8):

If you have a `@Transactional` annotation on method, Spring wraps the call to this method with aspect handling the transaction.

So:

1) Only public methodes can be wrapped in aspect

2) You call wrapped code only if you call the method on a bean taken from / injected by Spring container.

In your case:

1) The code isn't wrapped in transactional aspect because it is not public method

2) Event if it was, it is called directly from within the class, so you wouldn't call wrapped version anyway.

So the solution is to make separate bean with `@Transactional` method, inject it into and call it from `Response` class.

Of course you need `<tx:annotation-driven/>` in your spring-xml or instruct Spring otherwise to process `@Transactional` annotations (see the [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html)).

Comment: can you please check ... I have updated my answer .. and followed ur comments ...

Comment: How do you activate transactional support? Do you have <tx:annotation-driven/> in your XML file? Have you read the reference?

Comment: yes I did .. in my transactionManager "globalRollbackOnParticipationFailure" is set to false ..does that mean something ... is this the reason ..of not rolling back ??

Comment: Set the trap in debugger and check if you are inside proxy. I don't know what is transaction level portal - it is not standard one, supported by DB. If you are inside transactional proxy, then it could be DB issue or this PORTAL isolation level issue.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are outside the application context. You are creating a new instance of a class, NEW is bad in Spring, very bad. Get an instance of Test from the application context, not by creating a new instance unless you start your application context in Test. Try to Autowire test in your class you mention above or inject it from Spring and then let me know, but the code you are showing above will never work with transaction management.

Comment: check the edit 2 block ..done as you said ..still not working .... lastly ..can there be reason that I am calling "transactional" in another function with "transactional" ... mean I have nested @transactional in picture ... any Idea ??

Comment: At this point I have no idea what you are doing. You need to spend some time with Spring before you blindly create objects. Why don't you post some real code and show your entire call stack and configs, start over in other words because what you have now is unintelligible.

Comment: have already posted my complete code ...but one need to know about liferay yo completely understand it ..have no Idea  on which part to post of liferay internal .... yes but truly said it is getting rubbish ... thanks for the help ..will delete this post and create new one ..